# PHP - How to get cookies when logging into website?

Tags: php, authentication, curl, cookies

I tried getting the cookie file from logging into the site binweevils, but i am unable to do so.

I have entered the correct values to be posted to the API, but for some reason it is telling me to enable cookies.

```
function login() {
        $curl = curl_init("http://lb.binweevils.com/php2/login/logUserIn.php"); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        define('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "userID="."mo_salah"."&password="."test"."&rememberMe=1&submitted=1&x=".mt_rand(1, 200)."&y=".mt_rand(1, 100));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "sitecookies.txt");

        $header = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

        print($header);

        if(preg_match('/http:\/\/play\.binweevils.com\?res\=(.*?)\n/', $header))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

If anyone can help me with this, it will be deeply appreciated.

The point :  is to get cookies from this website.

Comment: If your website isn't *binweevils.com* then your browser **shouldn't** be making the cookie data available...

Comment: have you tried to parse header response for cookies?

Comment: site protected by Cloudflare.

Comment: Are you sure the webserver user can write `sitecookies.txt` from where it is running the php script?

Comment: Is there a way I can manually set cookies with CURL? instead of retrieving it